# Equivalent to sudo tee filename <<<"string" in fish

Tags: shell, fish

Right now I execute the following command in bash:

```
sudo tee /proc/acpi/nvhda <<<ON
```

However, I would like to use that command in fish instead of bash.
The <<< does not work in fish an throws an error.
What would be the equivalent in fish?

I tried to pipe an echo, but that throws me a permission denied.

```
sudo echo "ON" | /proc/acpi/nvhda
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an approach that works in fish just as effectively as it works in POSIX-family shells:

```
echo ON | sudo tee /proc/acpi/nvhda
```

There's no point to `sudo echo` -- `echo` just writes to the already-open stdout handle it inherited from its parent process; it doesn't open any files, so it doesn't *need* any permissions.

The point to `tee` is having a process *external from the shell* that can thus be on the other end of `sudo`. That works whether or not you have heredoc or herestring support in use.